# Handling Thousand of SKSpriteNodes in a scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am building a game using sprite kit and its a game where you send balls into a bucket and grow the bucket. As the buckets grow the balls (SKSpriteNodes) stay on the scene. Im trying to see how to keep high performance while managing thousands of nodes. Any idea how i can do this? After 700 or so the FPS in simulator goes below 10 tps.

Here is my code from my scene. Any help is appreciated.

```
//
//  GameScene.m
//

#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene
@synthesize _flowIsON;

NSString *const kFlowTypeRed = @"RED_FLOW_PARTICLE";
const float kRED_DELAY_BETWEEN_PARTICLE_DROP = 0.1; //delay for particle drop in seconds

static const uint32_t kRedParticleCategory         =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t kInvisbleWallCategory        =  0x1 << 1;

NSString *const kStartBtn = @"START_BTN";
NSString *const kLever = @"Lever";

NSString *const START_BTN_TEXT = @"Start Game";

CFTimeInterval lastTime;


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    [self initializeScene];

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];

        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:kStartBtn]) {
            [node removeFromParent];

            //initalize to ON
            _flowIsON = YES;

            //[self initializeScene];
        } else if ([node.name isEqualToString:kLever]) {

            _leverNode = (SKSpriteNode *)node;

            [self selectNodeForTouch:location];

        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint previousPosition = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];

    CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(positionInScene.x - previousPosition.x, positionInScene.y - previousPosition.y);

    [self panForTranslation:translation];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    float deltaTimeInSeconds = currentTime - lastTime;

    //NSLog(@"Time is %f and flow is %d",deltaTimeInSeconds, _flowIsON);

    if ((deltaTimeInSeconds > kRED_DELAY_BETWEEN_PARTICLE_DROP) && _flowIsON) {

        [self startFlow:kFlowTypeRed];

        //only if its been past 1 second do we set the lasttime to the current time
        lastTime = currentTime;

    }



}


- (void) initializeScene {

    SKLabelNode *startBtn = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

    startBtn.text = START_BTN_TEXT;
    startBtn.name = kStartBtn;
    startBtn.fontSize = 45;
    startBtn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:startBtn];

    //init to flow off
    _flowIsON = NO;

    // Set physics body delegate
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    self.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.view.showsDrawCount = YES;
    self.view.showsQuadCount = YES;


    //Set collision mask for invisible wall
    _nonWallNode =  (SKSpriteNode *) [self.scene childNodeWithName:@"NonWall"];
    _nonWallNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kInvisbleWallCategory;
    _nonWallNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kRedParticleCategory;
    _nonWallNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kRedParticleCategory | kInvisbleWallCategory;

}


- (void) startFlow:(NSString *)flowKey  {

//    //SKSpriteNode *redParticleEmitter = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RedFlowParticles"];
//    
//    SKShapeNode *redParticleEmitter = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
//    
//    CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
//    CGPathAddArc(myPath, NULL, 0,0, 15, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
//    redParticleEmitter.path = myPath;
//    
//    redParticleEmitter.lineWidth = 1.0;
//    redParticleEmitter.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
//    redParticleEmitter.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
//    redParticleEmitter.glowWidth = 0.5;
//    
//    //set size to 20px x 20px
//    //redParticleEmitter.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);


    SKSpriteNode *redParticleEmitter = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RedFlowParticles"];

    //set size to 20px x 20px
    redParticleEmitter.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);

    SKPhysicsBody *redParticleEmitterPB = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:redParticleEmitter.frame.size.width/2];
    redParticleEmitterPB.categoryBitMask = kRedParticleCategory;
    redParticleEmitterPB.collisionBitMask = kRedParticleCategory;
    redParticleEmitterPB.contactTestBitMask = kRedParticleCategory | kInvisbleWallCategory;

    //set this to 5% of the width of the scene
    redParticleEmitter.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.05, self.frame.size.height);
    redParticleEmitter.physicsBody =redParticleEmitterPB;
    redParticleEmitter.name = @"RedParticle";

    [self addChild:redParticleEmitter];



}

- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    //1
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    //2
    if(![_leverNode isEqual:touchedNode]) {

        [_leverNode removeAllActions];
        [_leverNode runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:0.0f duration:0.1]];

        _leverNode = touchedNode;
        //3
        if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kLever]) {
            SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction rotateByAngle:degToRad(-4.0f) duration:0.1],
                                                      [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.0 duration:0.1],
                                                      [SKAction rotateByAngle:degToRad(4.0f) duration:0.1]]];
            [_leverNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];
        }
    }

}


float degToRad(float degree) {
    return degree / 180.0f * M_PI;
}

- (CGPoint)boundLayerPos:(CGPoint)newPos {
    CGSize winSize = self.size;
    CGPoint retval = newPos;
    retval.x = MIN(retval.x, 0);
    retval.x = MAX(retval.x, -[self size].width+ winSize.width);
    retval.y = [self position].y;
    return retval;
}

- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {
    CGPoint position = [_leverNode position];
    if([[_leverNode name] isEqualToString:kLever]) {
        [_leverNode setPosition:CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y + translation.y)];
    }
//    else {
//        CGPoint newPos = CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y + translation.y);
//        [_background setPosition:[self boundLayerPos:newPos]];
//    }
}


# pragma mark -- SKPhysicsContactDelegate Methods

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *) contact {

    if (([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"RedParticle"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"NonWall"]) ||
        ([contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"RedParticle"] && [contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"NonWall"])) {

        //NSLog(@"Red particle Hit nonwall");

        //contact.bodyA.node.physicsBody.pinned = YES;
        //once red particle passes the invisible wall we need to stop it from going back through the wall


    }
}


- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *) contact {
    //NSLog(@"didEndContact called");

    if (([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"RedParticle"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"NonWall"]) ||
        ([contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"RedParticle"] && [contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"NonWall"])) {
       //NSLog(@"Red particle left");

        contact.bodyB.collisionBitMask = kRedParticleCategory | kInvisbleWallCategory;
        //once red particle passes the invisible wall we need to stop it from going back through the wall


    }
}


@end
```

Comment: I assume all the sprites already use the same texture / atlas, so there's no further optimizing in that direction.

Comment: Assuming that, once in the bucket the balls do not move anymore, you could move them to a separate node and cache its appearance into a texture (the caching of effect nodes comes to mind).

Comment: @NicolasMiari yes they Are all using the same image

Comment: See my answer for a plausible method to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create an additional sprite node on screen to display all your static balls as a whole (explained below).
2. Create an array of `CGPoint` to keep track of the positions of all balls that stopped.
3. At regular intervals, check all active ball sprites to see which ones have come to a stop.
4. For each ball that has stopped, remove that srpite from the scene and instead add its position (`CGPoint`) to the array described in #2.
5. Render an image consisting of one ball instance at each position in the array, and assign that image (texture) to the sprite node described in #1.
6. Go back to #3 and repeat.

---

**Note:** I haven't used SpriteKit for a while and I'm not sure how to implement point #5, but it shouldn't be too difficult. SKEffectNode has an option (`shouldRasterize`) to cache its appearance -i.e., render once and reuse the same image on all subsequent frames.

Regarding the "regular intervals" described in step #3, the actual value (for example, every 10 frames) will depend on your measured performance and the dynamics of your actual game; you need to find it yourself. If it is too often, the overhead of rendering the static balls texture over and over will cause a performance hit. Too far apart, and you will spend more frames than necessary rendering many still, separate sprites that could have otherwise been "grouped".

---

**Alternative Solution:**

Instead of removing the sprites from screen when each ball becomes static, you could instead move them into a different container node (as children of it), and have that node be rasterized instead of rendering anew each frame.

This keeps each ball as a separate SKSpriteNode instance (even when the ones that are stopped) and allows for SpriteKit physics bodies (not sure if sprites with different parents can collide with each other, though. Never used SpriteKit physics).

---

In any case, the performance hit due to collision detection **will** increase with the number of balls, independent of whether you draw them each frame or not. 
I don't know exactly what optimizations SpriteKit's physics does (e.g., prunning, etc.), but the naïve approach to collision between n objects is to test each object against every other object, so the worse case is O(n^2).

---

**Final Thoughts:**

Because you can safely assume that still balls do not move anymore, the "group" of still balls remains in the same shape all along (until new balls stop and are added, that is). 
Ideally, you could calculate the "envelope" (a possibly non-convex polygon, with rounded corners) and collision-test the moving balls against that. Still not a trivial task, but at least it helps you skip collision-testing against the static balls in the inside of the group, which should never collide anyway (they are "shielded" by the balls in the boundary of the group).

Comment: Looks like there is also collision detection in OPs code. This solution may not work well in that instance. Depending on the use.

Comment: He can perform the detection against the centers/radii of the static balls (the array from #2). Actual sprites are removed from screen, but the information on their position is still there.

Comment: This collision detection is all supplied by SpriteKit pretty much automatically, so it would be some extra work to do this manually, however you're correct providing these nodes don't need to move on impact with another. Honestly I can't really see a better solution to this problem besides the answer you have already posted.

Comment: I see, spritekit physics bodies... However, ad-hoc collision detection between circles is pretty straightforward; it shouldn't be hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem here is all those physics bodies,  you have a 1000 sprites checking 1000 other sprites whether or not they need to be colliding.  One way you can make this a little faster is to break your screen into sub sets and having your nodes collission detection only check the surrounding neighbor quadrants and its own for sprites.  EG.  break the screen into 9 sections,  the top left section has its own bit mask, and can only collide with sprites in the top left,middle top, middle center, and let center sections.  If this sprite moves to the middle top section, its category becomes middle top, and will only check sprites in the top left, middle top, top right, left center, middle center, and right center.  The less checks the nodes have to make  the better.